# Как правильно использовать проекты домены в Mule ESB?

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер

У меня есть несколько приложений mule которые используют свои библиотеки, и properties файлы. Работают они следующим образом:
При деплое в папку на сервере **mule_home/lib/user** кладутся все необходимые библиотеки и файлы.
При запуске приложений в mule эта папка по умолчанию попадает в **classpath**.

В каждом приложении через `property-placeholder` я могу обратится к нужному `properties` файлу.

Собираюсь сделать для всех приложений один проект-домен, в котором будут хранится все библиотеки, java-beans и все что необходимо для нескольких приложений. С учетом того что `properties` файлы остались доступны извне для других(для тестирования и администрирования).

Не смог пока разобраться, какая папка для проекта-домена включается в **classpath**, или как указать на какую либо папку.